# MAMP not working after upgrading to macOS Sierra (Library/logs folder missing)

Tags: mamp, macos-sierra

After upgrading my Macbook to macOS Sierra, MAMP is not working.
The following error appears in the MAMP Apache error log:

```
[error] No such file or directory: Couldn't bind unix domain socket /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/cgisock

[error] No such file or directory: could not log pid to file /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/httpd.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realised that the /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/ folder was missing. I added the folder manually and it now seems to work.

PS. I wonder how the installation of Sierra affected MAMP. Did this folder exist before and it was removed during the installation? Or does MAMP require a different folder structure on Sierra? Or was it just a coincidence that the problem occurred right after installing Sierra?